Wordpress Block - add_rewrite_rule doesn´t work
I created a Wordpress Plugin to display Events.
The plugin is developed via Wordpress Block and works fine. The url to the detail page is http://localhost:4444/?slug=02-12-2024_artist_name
To make it better readable, the url should look like http://localhost:4444/event/02-12-2024_artist_name
I added this code to my plugin.php script
add_action('init',  function () {
    add_rewrite_rule('event/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?slug=$matches[1]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_tag('%slug%', '([^&]+)');
    error_log("Rewrite rules added");
});

add_filter('query_vars', function ($query_vars) {
    $query_vars[] = 'slug';
    return $query_vars;
});

But the rewrite doesn´t work correctely and i get a 404 "page not found".
I tried to implement the render.php a second time (first time is via block.json), but I think it´s not the right way, cause I didn´t get my attributes
add_filter('template_include', function ($template) {
    if (get_query_var('slug') == false || get_query_var('slug') == '') {
        require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'src/render.php';
        return $template;
    }
});

Addition how I create the event:
class Blocks
{
    public static function init()
    {
        // Block-Registrierung
        add_action('init', [__CLASS__, 'promotion_block_init']);
    }

    // Block initialisieren und Bootstrap laden
    public static function promotion_block_init()
    {
        // Register the block from the build directory
        register_block_type(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '../build');
        // Optionale Einbindung von Bootstrap
        wp_register_style('bootstrap_handle', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    }
}

block.json in the plugins root
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 3,
    "name": "copilot/promotion",
    "version": "3.0.0",
    "title": "Copilot Promotion",
    "category": "widgets",
    "icon": "star-empty",
    "description": "Ausspielen deiner Events aus co*pilot",
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "attributes": {
        "isArchive": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false
        },
        "useFaceDetection": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false
        },
        "selectedPagination": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "20"
        },
        "selectedTemplate": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "list"
        }
    },
    "textdomain": "copilot",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": [
        "file:./style-index.css",
        "file:./style-view.css",
        "bootstrap_handle"
    ],
    "render": "file:./render.php",
    "viewScript": "file:./view.js"
}


<?php

$slug = "";
if (isset($_GET["copilot-slug"]) && preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9\-\+_]+$/", $_GET["copilot-slug"])) {
    $slug = $_GET["copilot-slug"];
}

if (!function_exists('render_copilot_block')) {
    function render_copilot_block($attributes, $slug)
    {
        $unique_id = uniqid('copilot-render-');
        $selectedTemplate = isset($attributes['selectedTemplate']) ? $attributes['selectedTemplate'] : 'list';
        $selectedPagination = isset($attributes['selectedPagination']) ? $attributes['selectedPagination'] : '20';
        $useFaceDetection = isset($attributes['useFaceDetection']) ? $attributes['useFaceDetection'] : 'false';
        $isArchive = isset($attributes['isArchive']) ? $attributes['isArchive'] : 'false';
        $pluginPath = plugins_url('', __FILE__) . "/../";

        echo '
        <div 
            id="' . esc_attr($unique_id) . '"
            class="w-100 copilot-render"
            data-copilotpluginpath="' . $pluginPath . '" 
            data-copilotslug="' . esc_attr($slug) . '" 
            data-copilottemplate="' . esc_attr($selectedTemplate) . '" 
            data-copilotpagination="' . esc_attr($selectedPagination) . '" 
            data-copilotusefacedetection="' . esc_attr($useFaceDetection) . '" 
            data-copilotisarchive="' . esc_attr($isArchive) . '" 
        ></div>
        ';
    }
}

render_copilot_block($attributes, $slug);

The view.tsx
// @ts-ignore
import domReady from "@wordpress/dom-ready";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
// @ts-ignore
import "./style.scss";

// @ts-ignore
import Banner from "./components/Banner";
import Events from "./components/Events";
import SingleEvent from "./components/SingleEvent";

domReady(() => {
    const copilotContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".copilot-render");

    // Loop through each element
    copilotContainers.forEach((container) => {
        const element = container as HTMLElement;
        const uniqueId = element.id;

        if (uniqueId) {
            const root = createRoot(element);
            root.render(<View attributes={element.dataset as Attributes} />);
        }
    });
});

type Attributes = {
    copilotslug: string;
    copilotpagination: string;
    copilottemplate: string;
    copilotpluginpath: string;
    copilotusefacedetection: string;
    copilotisarchive: string;
};

function View({ attributes }: { attributes: Attributes }) {
    const {
        copilotslug,
        copilottemplate,
        copilotpagination,
        copilotpluginpath,
        copilotusefacedetection,
        copilotisarchive,
    } = attributes;

    const useFaceDetection = copilotusefacedetection === "1";
    const isArchive = copilotisarchive === "1";

    if (copilottemplate === "banner") {
        return <Banner useFaceDetection={useFaceDetection} />;
    }

    if (copilotslug) {
        return <SingleEvent slug={copilotslug} />;
    }

    return (
        <Events
            selectedpagination={parseInt(copilotpagination)}
            isArchive={isArchive}
        />
    );
}


how is created this url with "slug" ? if it's a wordpress page or a custom post type, a pretty url already exists.

The url is created in my plugin
this is the existing path to the the event detail page
http://localhost:4444/?slug=02-12-2024_artist_name

edit your question to show us the code you use to create the events.

I added the complete workflow
